# How do i rectify my error in my mergesort implementation

Tags: c, sorting

This is my code of Mergesort but it's giving wrong output. I have no idea why.
I have tried to only include the essential details.  Please help me find out my mistake. Same is the problem with my quicksort implementation too.

```
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{

    int n1 = m - l + 1;

    int n2 = r - m;

    int L[n1], R[n2];
 

    for(int i = 0; i < n1; i++)

        L[i] = arr[l + i];

    for(int j = 0; j < n2; j++)

        R[j] = arr[m + 1 +j];
    int i = 0; 

    int j =0;

    int k = l;

     

    while (i < n1 && j < n2)

    {

        if (L[i] <= R[j]) 

        {

            arr[k] = L[i];

            i++;

        }

        else

        {

            arr[k] = R[j];

            j++;

        }

        k++;

    }

    while (i < n1) 

    {

        arr[k] = L[i];

        i++;

        k++;

    }
 
    while (j < n2)

    {

        arr[k] = R[j];

        j++;

        k++;

    }
}


void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r)
{

    if (l < r)

   {
        int m = l + (r - l) /2;
        mergeSort(arr, l, m);

        mergeSort(arr, m + 1, r);
 

        merge(arr, l, m, r);

    }
}
```

Suppose input here is 4,0,6,1,5,2,3
Output shown is 0,4,1,5,2,3,6

I have been trying for many hours please someone help

Comment: I tried to see step by step by printing my values of low,mid,high at each step but I couldn't find my error via that way

Comment: Please please please help I am going mad of looking at the program for 3 days

Comment: "I have tried to only include the essential details." that is good. But please do so by making a [mre] which demonstrats the problem. I recommend to use hardcoded sample data to simplify that.

Comment: Really need to see how you call `mergeSort` with some sample data.

Comment: Sorry, but merge sort should give in first pass (for 4,0,6,1,5,2,3): 0,4,6,1,2,3,5.  on next pass it should give 0,1,2,3,4,5,6.

Comment: So what should I do here?

Comment: you should [edit] your question and add a main method with static test data, so that anyone interested can copy&paste your code into their favorite editor and execute it. Maybe your implementation is correct and your call is wrong. We will never know unless you show it.

Comment: It has run finally thanks to grek40 I was going wrong in my call